# Indefinite integral $\int x\cot^2x\,dx$

Tags: integration

Approach that I have tried:

$u = x$ $\to$ $u' = 1$

$v'= \cot x\to v = \ln(\sin x)$

$$\int x\cot^2x\,dx=x\ln(\sin x)-\int\ln(\sin x)\,dx$$

And from there, I have a problem, because solving for integral of ln(sinx) gives complicated results with I doubt give correct final answer. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Is ctg the co-tangent function?

Comment: yes, cot function

Comment: You have apparently forgotten the square part of the integrand. $v'=\cot^2x\,dx,$ not $\cot x\,dx.$

Comment: Right, that solves everything, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int x\cot ^2 x d x & =\int x\left(\csc ^2 x-1\right) d x \\
& =-\int x d(\cot x)-\frac{x^2}{2} \\
& =-x \cot x+\int \cot x d x-\frac{x^2}{2} \\
& =-x \cot x+\int \frac{d(\sin x)}{\sin x}-\frac{x^2}{2} \\
& =-x \cot x+\ln |\sin x|-\frac{x^2}{2}+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just see that the problem have been solved, so just offer another possible solution=)

Let $u = \tan x$, we then have

$$\int x\cot^2x\,dx=\int \left(\frac{\arctan(u)}{u^2}-\frac{\arctan(u)}{u^2+1} \right) \, du$$
For the first part, apply integration by parts (let $v = \frac{1}{u}$); for the second part, let $s = \arctan(u)$.